# Foreman for Ruby on Rails starts fine on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I was able to start foreman fine on MacBook, but when I followed the exact same instructions on Windows, I got the following error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0/lib/foreman/
process.rb:55:in `spawn': Exec format error - bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENO
EXEC)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0
/lib/foreman/process.rb:55:in `block in run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0
/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `chdir'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0
/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `run'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like an environment variable issue to me; but am not quite sure.

Comment: Interestingly, I get a different error now!!:

A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would
 block
<internal:prelude>:76:in `__read_nonblock'
<internal:prelude>:76:in `read_nonblock'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in watch_for_output'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:373:in `loop'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0/lib/foreman/
engine.rb:373:in `block in watch_for_output'

Answer (score 3):

> Ruby users should take care not to install foreman in their project's
>   Gemfile.

foreman official github page states that. Just remove the line gem from GemFile and install it instead.

```
gem install foreman
```