# Foreman start on Windows 10 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpack-dev-server, foreman

#### Environment:

- Windows 10 x64
- Ruby: ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]
- Node: v16.13.1
- npm: 8.1.2

---

#### Problem Statement:

Running webpack script inside Rails project in Windows 10 x64 doesn't work properly.

It seems that the environment must be set before the exec for Windows

---

#### Exception:

Foreman start throwing below error

```
$ foreman start

Traceback (most recent call last):
        17: from C:/Ruby27/bin/foreman:23:in `<main>'
        16: from C:/Ruby27/bin/foreman:23:in `load'
        15: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        14: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        13: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        12: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        11: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        10: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/cli.rb:42:in `start'
         9: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:57:in `start'
         8: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `spawn_processes'
         7: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `each'
         6: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `block in spawn_processes'
         5: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `upto'
         4: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_processes'
         3: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `run'
         2: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `chdir'
         1: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `spawn': Exec format error - bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOEXEC)
```

---

#### Configuration:

`GemFile`

```
ruby "2.7.2"
gem "rails", "~> 6.0"
gem "webpacker", "< 6"

group :development do
  gem "foreman", require: false
end
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.15.3",
    "npm": ">=6",
    "yarn": ">=1.15.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "webpack": "4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "3"
  },
}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

However, executing `bin/webpack-dev-server` on a separate terminal is compiling properly.

```
$ bin/webpack-dev-server

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3035/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /packs/
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\DELL\path\project\plate\public\packs
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
i ｢wdm｣: Hash: 3f9f73c5cf41d5c81ee8
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 4740ms
Built at: 12/01/2022 14:01:39
                                     Asset       Size       Chunks                         Chunk Names
    js/application-f0238c055e7bba05cd93.js    515 KiB  application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
js/application-f0238c055e7bba05cd93.js.map    581 KiB  application  [emitted] [dev]        application
                             manifest.json  364 bytes               [emitted]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I tried removing `foreman` from `Gemfile` and re-installing it using `gem` command by [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273377)

`Gemfile`

```
group :development do
  # gem "foreman", require: false
end
```

```
$ gem uninstall foreman
$ gem install foreman
```

> `gem uninstall foreman` is removing the `foreman` from the ruby main directory itself.

---

#### **EDIT 3:**

I tried [`bundle exec rails webpacker:install`](https://gitmotion.com/webpacker/236249976/command-webpack-dev-server-not-found) but again `foreman start` is throwing same error. While `bin/webpack-dev-server` is compiling properly on PORT as `config/webpack` file.

```
$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install

  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
   identical  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config
       exist  config/webpack
   identical  config/webpack/development.js
   identical  config/webpack/environment.js
   identical  config/webpack/production.js
   identical  config/webpack/test.js
Copying postcss.config.js to app root directory
   identical  postcss.config.js
Copying babel.config.js to app root directory
   identical  babel.config.js
Copying .browserslistrc to app root directory
   identical  .browserslistrc
The JavaScript app source directory already exists
       apply  C:/Users/DELL/Documents/project/plate/vendor/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.3/lib/install/binstubs.rb
  Copying binstubs
       exist    bin
   identical    bin/webpack
   identical    bin/webpack-dev-server
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [5.4.3]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker@5.4.3 from "."
yarn add v1.22.15
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.22.17", while you're on "1.22.15".
info To upgrade, download the latest installer at "https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi".
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 8.92s.
Installing webpack and webpack-cli as direct dependencies
         run  yarn add webpack@^4.46.0 webpack-cli@^3.3.12 from "."
yarn add v1.22.15
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 6.82s.
Installing dev server for live reloading
         run  yarn add --dev webpack-dev-server@^3 from "."
yarn add v1.22.15
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 7.33s.
Webpacker successfully installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new file named "Procfile" on root of your project.
Insert the following in the Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

Now you will be able to run your server using command

```
heroku local
```

on http://localhost:5000.

Comment: I'm not using `heroku` above issue is on development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I simply run `gem uninstall foreman` and `gem install foreman` then bundle install.
This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `ps` to list running processes. Kill ruby process by `kill -9 <pid>`
- Change `bin/rails` to `rails` inside Procfile.dev (ex: `web: rails server` and `css: rails tailwindcss:watch`)
- Run `bin/dev`